# Opencart fixed shipping prices with different currencys

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I got two currencies. € (geozone germany) and CHF (geozone switzerland). Both currencies should have weight base shipping applied.

Important is, that both currencies should have FIXED shipping costs. E.G.

Shipping costs for € - 5.00 €

Shipping costs for CHF – 8.00 CHF

The exchange rate of CHF to € is changing every day. Because it is only possible to add the shipping rates in the default currency (€), the shipping costs of CHF changes every day.

That is bad. Anyone knows how to come around this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want currencies to fluctuate you can go to **Admin > System > Settings > Edit** and under the **Local** tab set **Auto Update Currency** to **No**.  Now set your exchange rate and shipping rates accordingly and they will not change.

If you need currencies to stay up to date but only want your shipping to be an exception, you'll need to modify the shipping model file to adjust the cost relative to the selected currency's current exchange rate.